# Does Record type prevent users from viewing records?

Tags: record-type

can you prevent users from seeing different record types? I want to lock down users from being able to view different record types but it seems that are able to do it in a report would i be able to lock that down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to [rethink the sharing model](http://na5.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/managing_the_sharing_model.htm).
There are several levels of granting access but each of them widens the permissions, you never can use sharing rules etc to revoke something.

So you'd have to start with Organization Wide Defaults = private (and perhaps also "grant access using hierarchies not selected). And then indeed - you could use sharing rules ("criteria based sharing rules" to be precise) to grant access based on record types.

Answer (score 2):

Users can view records of all record types so as long as they have read access to the object and sharing (at least read) access to the record.

The explicit record type settings on the profile control which RecordTypes can the user creates records for, if they have write access on the object.

What you could do is assign a very minimal and locked down page layout for the record types you want to protect, so the users can see next to nothing.

Comment: But Elliot's concern is that they're able to bypass the limited page layout with reporting anyway ;) So my guess is he has already tried it.